# Cakephph 3.0 - Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: cakephp

m using cakephp 3.0 and m using bin/cake bake all for baking all views. but m getting error while baking dependent view..like previously i had baked views for products using

```
bin/cake bake all products
```

but when i use same for

```
bin/cake bake all products_mix
```

m getting following error

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'cakephp3_s.products_mix' doesn't exist in
[/home/shital/public_html/cakephp3/myCakeApp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php,
line 130] 2015-02-20 06:35:57 Error: [Cake\Database\Exception]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'cakephp3_s.products_mix' doesn't exist
```

can anyone please help me for this error.. m not getting actually what mistake m making here???

Answer (score 2):

When you use cakePHP follow naming conventions or it will simply wont work.

`bin/cake bake all products_mix` is wrong table name . As you **must** use plural name for view . Remember in cakephp all names are Plurals **exept** your model.

I suggest you to use another grammatical proper name for view. Like say `product_tags` , `product_attributes` . See if there are multiple words for view , then make last word plural .

In other case if you have HABTM(Has And Belongs To Many) relationship, you should make both words plural. Like `users_courses` , here it connects to users,courses tables ,and contain Foreign key to those tables. So by naming convention HABTM table has both words pluralized.

Fore conventions in cakePHP ,refer [Link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html).

Comment: Don't forget that the question is about 3.x!

Comment: Ok.. thanks.. its working now..i had tried it for product_tags and it's working proper.... i'll follow proper naming conventions from now onwards.

Answer (score 1):

As per CakePHP's conventions all table names should be plural not singular , so that's the first thing you should fix. products_mix in not a proper one.

Comment: Ok thanks..it's simply due to naming convention.. working now.